# Loading one field in lucene index

Tags: c#, java, .net, lucene, lucene.net

Whats the fastest way to loading all of the values of a lucene index field in memory,
I have large lucene index (1.6 GB) i need to load all of the (ID) field into memory with least overhead on memory I'm getting OutOfMemoryException when i iterate through all of the items and read that field (this is also very slow for loading field of index i need a solution with better performance).

Comment: Can you explain how you currently do it? And/or post the code.

Comment: 1.6 GiB sounds like a big index. I've got an index of 1.4 million works, about 40 fields, and it takes 1.1 GiB non-optimized. Could you give us some numbers for your index, perhaps checking if you store fields unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to address why you need to load of your Fields into memory in the first place?

Have you tried doing a search using a [TermQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html) and a Term that simply contains the field you want to load? e.g. new Term("ID").

You then wont need to load all values into memory to iterate over them. Instead, use a [FieldSelector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldSelector.html) to ensure only a single field is loaded when you load each search result.

Otherwise, use Lucene's [FieldCache](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCache.html) to get the values for all your ID fields.

Comment: FieldCache is the way to go. It wont require you to store the fields, it's enough having them indexed non-analyzed.